# Recursively cancel an allOf CompletableFuture

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

If I have

```
CompletableFuture<Something> future1 = service.request(param1);
CompletableFuture<Something> future2 = service.request(param2);
CompletableFuture<Void> many = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2);
```

what will happen when I do `many.cancel()`? Will `future1` and `future2` be cancelled as well? If not, what would be the cleanest way to achieve this? I'm reluctant to hold on to `future1` and `future2`, just to be able to cancel them when I want to cancel `many`.

Some background on why I want this: when receiving a piece of data, I need to request matching, potentially future data to perform a computation. If a newer piece of data arrives, I want to cancel the completion of the earlier computation, because the result will immediately be superceded by the new computation.

Comment: Just tested: cancelling many doesn't cancel future1 and future2.

Comment: You will need to cancel internal futures, then `many` will be completed with `CancellationException[]`.

Comment: I kind of assumed that already, because I've been thinking about this some more: `future1` might be part of more than 1 `allOf` sets! So it is not trivial, that's probably why it hasn't been implemented...

Comment: Just keep in mind: whether you cancel `many` or each of the input futures is irrelevant. The effect is the same.

Comment: @Holger, the same as in "the same for all three futures" or as in "the same for composite future"? I'm not quite sure cancelling a composite does anything to futures it composed of.

Comment: Did you try `CompletableFuture.anyOf(service.awaitNeverPiece(), CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2));`?

Comment: @MProkhorov: “The effect is the same” doesn’t imply that the effect is what the OP has in mind. In this case, it rather implies that calling `cancel` on the components is unlikely to have more effect than just calling `cancel` on the composite. I have elaborated the issue in my answer…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before you make you life harder than necessary, you should become aware of what cancelling a `CompletableFuture` actually does. Most important, it does *not* stop the associated computation.

If a computation associated with a `CompletableFuture` is already running, but has not completed yet, cancelling a `CompletableFuture` turns it into the “cancelled” state, which may have an immediate effect on all dependent stages, but not on the computation, which will continue until complete, though its attempt to complete the cancelled future will not have any effect.

While other `Future`’s might be cancelled with interruption, which will stop the computation, if it checks for interruption, this doesn’t apply to `CompletableFuture`, see [`CompletableFuture.cancel(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-):

> #### Parameters:
>
> mayInterruptIfRunning - this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.

So when you cancel either, `future1` or `future2`, successfully, the only immediate effect would be the cancellation of `many`, which you can also achieve by calling `cancel` on `many` itself. It would have a broader effect, if there were more dependent stages, but since you stated, that you don’t want to keep references to `future1` or `future2`, this doesn’t seem to be the case.

The following code demonstrates the behavior:

```
CompletableFuture<String> supply = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(2));
    System.out.println("supplying value");
    return "foo";
});
CompletableFuture<String> then = supply.thenApply(s -> {
    System.out.println("Evaluating next stage");
    return s;
});
CompletableFuture<?> last = then.handle((s,t) -> {
    System.out.println("last stage: value: "+s+", throwable: "+t);
    return "";
});
System.out.println("cancelling: "+supply.cancel(true));
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

This code reproducible prints:

```
last stage: value: null, throwable: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
canceling: true
supplying value
```

(the order might change)

regardless of whether you call `supply.cancel(true)` or `then.cancel(true)` or whether you pass `true` or `false`; it won’t stop the ongoing `Supplier` evaluation.

There will be a difference, if the associated computation hasn’t been started yet and it does check the cancellation state when starting, like with the actions produced by the convenience methods in `CompletableFuture`. This is a rare situation, as normally, your `service.request(paramN)` call is supposed to trigger the evaluation.

It’s a fundamental property of the `CompletableFuture`, as its name suggests, that it is *completable*, i.e. anyone could call `complete` on it, thus, the `CompletableFuture` can’t control whoever might eventually call `complete` on it in the future. So all, `cancel` can achieve, is to set it to the cancelled state, which implies ignoring subsequent completion attempts and propagating the cancellation downward to the dependent actions.

---

So the bottom line is that you might already be fine with just calling `cancel` on the `many` instance, because calling `cancel` on `future1` and `future2` is unlikely to have an effect that is worth the complication of your code.

Answer (score 4):

The tree constructed by `CompletableFuture.allOf` doesn't hold any references to the given instances of `CompletableFuture`. Instead if just builds *completion* tree, which is *is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete* (from [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-)).

So probably you have to keep references to all `CompletableFuture` in order to cancel them sequentially when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for my library: https://github.com/vsilaev/tascalate-concurrent

It provides both truly cancelable CompletionStage implementations (CompletableTask) as well as methods to combine them (Promises.all)

```
CompletionStage<Something> future1 = CompletableTask
  .complete(param1, myExecutor).thenApplyAsync(this::serviceCall);
CompletionStage<Something> future2 = CompletableTask
  .complete(param2, myExecutor).thenApplyAsync(this::serviceCall);

Promise<List<Something>> many = Promises.all(future1, future2);
```

Now you can call `many.cancel(true)` and both `future1` and `future2` will be cancelled (if not yet completed). Moreover, if either of individual futures completes exceptionally, then another one will be cancelled automatically (again, if not yet completed).

Comment: The answer looks much better now @Valery. I've deleted my previous comment since it is no longer relevant.