# How to interrupt CompletableFuture::join?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, interrupt, completable-future

I've found that `CompletableFuture::join` seems **uninterruptible** when not completed:

```
// CompletableFuture::join implementation from JDK 8 sources
public T join() { 
    Object r;
    return reportJoin((r = result) == null ? waitingGet(false) : r);
}
```

In above implementation, `waitingGet(false)` will ignore the interrupt flag of the working `Thread` and continue waiting. I'm wondering how can I interrupt a `Thread` in which I call `CompletableFuture::join`.

Comment: I wonder if this is what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389894/recursively-cancel-an-alloff-completablefuture/43391133#43391133

Comment: @Eugene Thank you for the link. I do know `CompletableFuture::cancel` won't interrupt the thread. What I want to do is to interrupt a thread which blocks in a `CompletableFuture::join` operation. Maybe I should describe my question more clearly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not use `join()` if you want to support interruption, use `get()` instead. Basically they are the same except:

- `join()` is only defined in `CompletableFuture` whereas `get()` comes form interface `Future`
- `join()` wraps exceptions in `CompletionException` whereas `get()` wraps them in `ExecutionException`
- `get()` might be interrupted and would then throw an `InterruptedException`

Note that what you interrupt is the `Thread`, not the `Future`. For example, the following code interrupts the main thread while it is waiting on `myFuture.get()`:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> myFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Interrupting…");
        mainThread.interrupt();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Completing");
        myFuture.complete(null);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
try {
    myFuture.get();
    System.out.println("Get succeeded");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Get failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
Interrupting…
Get failed
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:347)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at CompletableFutureInteruption.main(CompletableFutureInteruption.java:37)
    …
```

If you replace `get()` by `join()`, the interrupt will indeed not work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the differences between `join()` and `get()`.

Comment: The method `join()` is defined in `CompletableFuture`, not `CompletionStage` (first bullet point). Though the interface and implementation appear tightly coupled considering the `toCompletableFuture()` method of `CompletionStage`.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw, I fixed that  now

Answer (score 2):

I finally give up to interrupt the Thread which blocks in waiting for `CompletableFuture::join` finish.

Instead I use `CompletableFuture::allof` to get a `CompletableFuture` *all* which ends when all my joined Futures end. And then just call the `get()` method of the *all* Future in the working thread. When `get()` returns, I then collect all my results by iterating all my joined Futures and call `getNow` on them. Such a procedure is interruptible.

Comment: Looks like this was [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/167668) then…

Comment: @DidierL Yes, I just want an interruptible way to "join" all the Futures and get the results. I should clarify with that.

Comment: I don't see how the `allOf()` and the interrupts are actually related to one another here. Either `allOf()` solves the problem without interrupts, or you need interrupts but it does not matter that you are working on the result of an `allOf()` call.

Comment: It is `get()` that is related to interrupts. You are right.
Actually I had a bunch of Futures and wanted to join them and get the results. So I mentioned `allOf()` combined with `get()`.

Comment: So how did you actually do an interruption ? example please ?

Answer (score 0):

I clearly known in the end you are **not** actually looking for the **interruptible**, but as a way around it can be interrupted by **exceptions** as follows (though it's `join()`):

```
private static void testCompleteExceptionally() {
    String name = "Hearen";
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture
            = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        delay(500L);
        if (name == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Computation error!");
        }
        return "Hello, " + name;
    });

    if (name != null) {
        completableFuture.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("Calculation failed!"));
    }
    out.println(completableFuture.handle((s, t) ->  s != null ? s : "Hello, Stranger!" + t.toString()).join());
}
```